# how to Optimize the Listbox binding C# code by JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, dropdown

When I go back to a page by clicking the back button:

```
protected void TsrProc_BackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/TSP/TSR_SearchList.aspx?rtn=1&bl=1");
}
```

I receive the following error:

> long running script error after sometime in IE 11

and in Chrome:

> following page has become unresponsive

When returning back I am binding 5-6 dropdownlist (and this error comes when I select all of the building in the dropdown list).

One of the dropdown list C# code is like this:

```
if (Request.QueryString("rtn").Equals("1")) {
    filterValue = Session["SEARCHWORKREQUEST"];
    string buildingsFilter = filterArray(1);
    List<string> buildings = new List<string>();

    foreach (string buildingsitem in buildingsFilter.Split(",")) {
        if (buildingsitem.Trim().Equals(string.Empty)) {
            continue;
        }
        buildings.Add(buildingsitem);
        if ((drpBuilding.Items.FindByValue(buildingsitem) != null)) {
            drpBuilding.Items.FindByValue(buildingsitem).Selected = true;
        }
    }
}

// binding the building dropdown

private void BindBuildingList()
{
    this.drpBuilding.Items.Clear();

    List<PulseResponse.BLL.Building> lstBuildings = default(List<PulseResponse.BLL.Building>);

    lstBuildings = this.mBuildingBLL.Get_ContactSiteBuildingsList(
        p_ContactID: UserWrapper.GetCurrentUser().ContactID,
        p_ShowInactive: false);

    if (lstBuildings.Count > 0) {
        this.drpBuilding.Enabled = true;
        this.drpBuilding.DataSource = lstBuildings;
        this.drpBuilding.DataTextField = "Building";
        this.drpBuilding.DataValueField = "BuildingID";
        this.drpBuilding.DataBind();
    } else {
        this.drpBuilding.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fast the code by jQuery/Javascript (binding the dropdown again)?

Comment: The for-each section you are using is infinitely looping through. 
That is the reason browser becoming unresponsive.
could you post your code where you are making an binding request?

Comment: @HEGDE updated the code.here we 1st getting all the buidling then filter the buidling user selected via session

Comment: Are you binding dropdown values with in
`if(!IsPostBack){//...}` section?

Comment: @HEGDE using SP 'lstBuildings = this.mBuildingBLL.Get_ContactSiteBuildingsList(p_ContactID: UserWrapper.GetCurrentUser().ContactID, p_ShowInactive: false);

Comment: No,
I got your point.
My query is Whether you are binding this  dropdown on backbutton click
within `if(!IspostBack){}` section or simply calling on a function?

Comment: This is all server-side code; usually long running script is from something running on the client-side browser, so do you know what that might be?  Normally that message doesn't show from server-side code...

Comment: @HEGDE yes if(!IsPostBack)

Comment: @HEGDE it's a listbox. sorry

Comment: Put  a debugger at `BindBuildingList()` and check where it is breaking.
One reason could be On backbutton click `BindBuildingList()` is called infinitely  as I mentioned Earlier.
Try putting Whole code within `if(!IspostBack){}` section
possibly it may help.

Comment: actually it's causing problem when i am selecting all the building i.e 150 (number) works good if it's less than that

Comment: @HEGDE is there any way to do it by Jquery(binding Listbox) ?

Comment: Make an ajax  request  and bind the values on postback,
it's a client-side binding and shouldn't take much time apart from call to ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the listbox will be rendered as

[image: like this]

in  browser

Secondly, you could call web methods to retrieve data from database using jQuery AJAX, and you could dynamically add `<option>` to listbox based on returned data in AJAX success callback function.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "page/yourmethodname",
        data: "{'Key':'value'}",//if any otherwise leave
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //add new options to ListBox dynamically
    //use for loop to iterate through kay-val pair and bind
for(var i=0i<data.length;i++){
 var newoption = '<option value='+data[i].key+'>'+data[i].value+'</option>';
            $("#ListBox1").append(newoption);
}

        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    })
```

Comment: my listbox runat server and by this code i will not able to get the value server side

Comment: You can get the value,
instead of `$("#ListBox1")`  either you have to use `($("#<%=ListBox1.ClientID%>")` 
or You can go for a class `.ListBox1` to get Value in jquery